# iOS - GPUImageFramebuffer Assertion failure

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I am getting this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Tried to overrelease a
>   framebuffer, did you forget to call -useNextFrameForImageCapture
>   before using -imageFromCurrentFramebuffer?'

This error does not happen when I apply my filters to an image like this:

ViewController

```
self.editImageView = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width - bgPadding, self.view.frame.size.width - bgPadding)];
[self.editImageView setCenter:[self makeCenterWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - self.toolBar.frame.size.height)]];
[self.editImageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.editImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
[self.editImageView setBackgroundColorRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0];
[self.view addSubview:self.editImageView];

FirstFilter *filter = [[FirstFilter alloc] init];
[filter imageWithFilter:0.15f inputImage:self.editImage imageView:self.editImageView];
```

FirstFilter.m

```
-(void)imageWithFilter:(float)value inputImage:(UIImage *)image imageView:(GPUImageView *)gpuImageView
{
    //background picture setup
    backgroundPicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:image smoothlyScaleOutput:YES];

    gaussianBlurFilter = [[GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter alloc] init];
    [gaussianBlurFilter setBlurRadiusInPixels:1.0f];

    opacityFilter = [[GPUImageOpacityFilter alloc] init];
    [opacityFilter setOpacity:0.1f];

    [backgroundPicture addTarget:gaussianBlurFilter];
    [gaussianBlurFilter addTarget:opacityFilter];

    //yellow picture setup
    GPUImagePicture *yellowPicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:[self imageFromColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:247.0f/255.0f green:209.0f/255.0f blue:148.0f/255.0f alpha:0.7f]] smoothlyScaleOutput:NO];

    //red picture setup
    GPUImagePicture *redPicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:[self imageFromColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:225.0f/255.0f green:49.0f/255.0f blue:90.0f/255.0f alpha:0.15f]] smoothlyScaleOutput:NO];

    //blend setup
    softlightBlendFilter = [[GPUImageSoftLightBlendFilter alloc] init];
    GPUImageSoftLightBlendFilter *softBlend = [[GPUImageSoftLightBlendFilter alloc] init];

    //blend
    sourcePicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:image smoothlyScaleOutput:YES];

    [sourcePicture addTarget:softlightBlendFilter];
    [yellowPicture addTarget:softlightBlendFilter];
    [softlightBlendFilter addTarget:softBlend];
    [redPicture addTarget:softBlend];

    [softBlend useNextFrameForImageCapture];

    GPUImageView *imageView = (GPUImageView *)gpuImageView;
    [softBlend addTarget:imageView];

    [sourcePicture processImage];
    [backgroundPicture processImage];
    [yellowPicture processImage];
    [redPicture processImage];
}
```

But the app crashes with error when I call `imageWithFilter:inputImage:imageView:` from a different place? Like this..

```
//mainContainerButton is a UIButton
GPUImageView *imageView = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:mainContainerButton.frame];
[imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
[imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[imageView setBackgroundColorRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0];
[mainContainerButton addSubview:imageView];

FirstFilter *filter = [[FirstFilter alloc] init];
[filter imageWithFilter:0.15f inputImage:(UIImage *)[contentArray objectAtIndex:i] imageView:(GPUImageView *)imageView];
```

I also tried commenting this line of code in `GPUImageFramebuffer.m` and the crash didn't happen and I get my image with filter.

```
NSAssert(framebufferReferenceCount > 0, @"Tried to overrelease a framebuffer, did you forget to call -useNextFrameForImageCapture before using -imageFromCurrentFramebuffer?");
```

What did I miss in my code?

Comment: What happens if you make yellowPicture, redPicture, and softBlend instance variables instead of local variables? The first two will be deallocated once that method exits, which will do bad things to your filter chain and may trigger a crash. The error you're seeing most likely has to do with the usage of `-useNextFrameForImageCapture` on the second blend in a set of two. That's a degenerate case in my framebuffer caching, and there's not much that can be done about it at present. I'm working on a more permanent solution.

Comment: Hi Brad. Thanks for your reply. I tried commenting `[softBlend useNextFrameForImageCapture];` and it still works with no crash when I call this method in my ViewController. I also tried making yellowPicture, redPicture, and softBlend instance variables, commenting `[softBlend useNextFrameForImageCapture];` and call this method from the second place in my question and it crashes with the same error. Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: Is it okay for me to comment out `NSAssert(framebufferReferenceCount > 0, @"Tried to overrelease a framebuffer, did you forget to call -useNextFrameForImageCapture before using -imageFromCurrentFramebuffer?");`?